# Mongodb: nested field in $group's _id

Tags: mongodb

Assume we have documents like this in the collection

```
{
    _id: {
        element_id: '12345',
        name: 'foobar'
    },
    value: {
        count: 1
    }
}
```

I am using the aggregation framework to do a `$group`, like so

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: '$_id.element_id', total: { $sum: '$value.count' } } }
])
```

And got a result of

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : null, "total" : 1 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

*Notice that the `_id` field in the result is null.* From experimentation it seems that $group is not allowing a nested field declaration for its `_id` (e.g. `$_id.element_id`).

Why is this? And is there a workaround for it?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly result should be shown? What should be on $_id. Are you try adding only { $group: { _id: '$_id', total: ...

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the detail. I've also found the answer on my own, which I will post. But don't hesitate if you have anything to add.

Answer (score 12):

I found a workaround using `$project`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { element_id: '$_id.element_id', count: '$value.count' } },
    { $group: { _id: '$element_id', total: { $sum: '$count' } } }
])
```

> $project Reshapes a document stream by renaming, adding, or removing fields.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project

Answer (score 3):

This turns out to have been issue [SERVER-7491](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7491). It appears to have been fixed in 2.2.2 (released about 3 days ago).

The workaround mentioned above worked well for me in 2.2.1. As a note, when using the $project workaround (pre 2.2.2) excluding _id from the $project with _id:0 is inadvisable as it appears to behave quite strangely, I ended up with some working properly and some where that portion of the _id field was missing in the end result within the same aggregation.